# Running Unit Tests on NodeJS with Jenkins

Tags: node.js, jenkins

How might I setup Jenkins to start my Node.JS Testing Server, run Unit Test probably JSTestDriver/Jasmine, and then top Node.JS?

I can start Node.JS using Execute Shell, but it "hangs" the build (expected since Node runs as a daemon)

Comment: What are you using Node.Js for?

Comment: @GarethOwen, In this case, a stub API for testing, since the real API is developed by another team

Answer (score 5):

I've written an article that explains how I've managed to run my unit tests with Mocha and ant.

The basic idea is:

- Set your environment variables so that jenkins can control them
- Use mocha's xunit reporter to generate a result report
- Use Jenkins' Publish JUnit test result report option to read the result report.

[You can read the full article here](http://johnhamelink.com/testing-nodejs-with-jenkins.html).

Comment: Also I would recommend using mocha's TAP reporter and Jenkins' publish TAP results plugin. Why? Because xunit will error if you have console.log messages that are not valid xml. TAP doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

JSTestDriver outputs it's results in a xUnit compliant xml format. Which the Hudson 'xUnit' plugin can then interpret.

We are planning to integrate jsTestDriver into Jenkins. To test our javaScript code in a selection of supported browsers.

Answer (score -1):

there is a plugin to execute nodejs with possibility to choice the nodejs  version

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NodeJS+Plugin

Comment: A quick scan of this plugin doesn't reveal anything about unit testing.  Can you please clarify how you use this plugin to do this?

Comment: i don't know if you use a pipeline or not so you have all documentations here
https://plugins.jenkins.io/nodejs/